# paging ViewComponent ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I want to design **my own** table, that has sorting, search, paging and so on and I want to reuse it on multiple pages.

To my understanding, I should make it as a ViewComponent, but I cannot find how to write/handle actions, work with get parameters and so on.

So: How do I implement ViewComponent (or something else), that is able to work with provided data and do stuff with them (like paging) preferably with url parameters?

Comment: `ViewComponent` is asp.net-core-mvc

Comment: "How to create a ViewComponent" is too broad and properly addressed [in the documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components.html). Do you have a specific question?

Comment: I don't know how to do "trip back to the server" with view component. Say that I do "top articles" component that shows first 5 articles, but I want user to be able to click on "next 5 articles" and the component should change.

Comment: I would do the following (based on the info you've given). Have your ViewComponent which is your 'output' to be used in several views. To stop the page refreshing when you want the 'next 5 articles' have a separate action (in a controller) that accepts an Ajax call and either (a) returns the next 'page' as JSON which you can parse & place into your view with JS or (b) returns HTML you can place into your view. You could even pass a parameter (via Ajax & a controller action) to the ViewComponent to either output a full 'component' or just the 'page' data.

Comment: Thanks, but I have since moved to Angular and right now, I don't remember all the issues that I had with that. But still, If I use ajax, I'll basically have two implementations.